# Express does not render error

Tags: node.js, express

I have this:

```
//public source
app.use('/src', express.static(__dirname + '/../client/source'));

//Errors
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
app.use(function(err, req, res) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.end('ERROR 404!');
});
```

When server not finding file, created an error is generated and assigned status 404 and error transmitted to next function. Then next function render phrase `ERROR 404!`. But in practice this does not work. On error server return to browser phrase `Error: Not found` and stacktrace, pointing to a line with `var err = new Error('Not Found');`. `res.end` get no result. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error handling middleware must have arity of 4;

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) { // this line
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.end('ERROR 404!');
});
```

[Have a look at the docs:](http://expressjs.com/es/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.error-handling)

> An error-handling middleware has an arity of 4, which must always be maintained to be identified as an error-handling middleware. Even if you don’t need to use the next object, make sure specify it to maintain the signature, else it will be interpreted as a regular middleware, and fail to handle errors.